# How to show selected option name inside the mat-select-trigger tags using Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to show Subtext in selectbox as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

my .html code is:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-select placeholder="country" [formControl]="country" >
    <mat-select-trigger>
     {{country.name}}         
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">
      {{country.name}} 
      <span class="example-additional-selection">
       Staff ID: {{country.id}}
      </span>  
       <span class="example-additional-selection">
       Staff Name:  {{country.firstname}}
      </span>  
      <span class="example-additional-selection">
       Staff Type:  {{country.staff}}
      </span>
      </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</form>
```

my .ts code is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'select-custom-trigger-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-custom-trigger-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-custom-trigger-example.css'],
})
export class SelectCustomTriggerExample {
   countries = [
       {id: 1, name: "United States", staff: "Sales", firstname: "Mark"},
       {id: 2, name: "Australia", staff: "Sales", firstname: "John"},
       ...
     ];
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      country: new FormControl(null)
    })
  }

  get country(): string {
    return this.form ? this.form.get('country').value : '';
  }
}
```

I am able to list the subtexts in the selectbox but I am unable to show the selected value.
When I put a static text inside the `mat-select-trigger` tags it works but when I put the variable `{{country.name}}` I get the following error

> Error: Cannot read property 'name' of null

here is the stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wd3vba-34arlh
I would appreciate if you can have a look and tell me where I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There error in your stackblitz

> Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

is telling you that the control `country` cannot be found on the component. The code has a property getter that does not return a `FormControl` which is what the template is expecting. You have some options.

---

Update the getter to return a `FormControl` and **not** a `string`

```
get country(): FormControl {
  return this.form.controls['country'] as FormControl;
}
```

---

Remove the getter and update the template to locate the control in the `FormGroup`

```
[formControl]="form.controls.country"
```

---

Remove the getter and create a direct reference to the `FormControl` on the component.

```
form: FormGroup;
country: FormControl;

constructor() {
  this.country = new FormControl();
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    country: this.country,
  });
}
```

---

#### Edit

To get the name use a safe navigation operator `?.`

```
{{form.controls.country.value?.name}} - selected text goes here
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wd3vba-ac1g8i)

Comment: Thanks Igor for the reply. when replace `selected text goes here` with `<mat-select-trigger> {{country.name}}</mat-select-trigger>` It still shows me an empty text when I select an option

Comment: @david83 - Did you see the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wd3vba-ac1g8i) link in my answer? That stackblitz is your stackblitz modified according to my answer. It works the way you want it to based on your question.

Comment: @david83 - also if you are adding a `FormControl` named `country` remove the property getter by the same name like I did in the stackblitz.

Comment: can you check your stackblitz link because I still have`<mat-select-trigger>
       selected text goes here
    </mat-select-trigger>` I want to show the selected option name in there. when I put  `{{country}}` It shows me `[object object]` when I put `{{country.name}}` nothing is showed.

Comment: @david83 - see update, use the safe navigation operator: `{{form.controls.country.value?.name}} - selected text goes here`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.

Comment: @david83 - glad to help.

Comment: @david83 - see [DatePicker Internationalization](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#internationalization). You can specify the locale of Australia and it should work fine. You can also use [moment.js](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#setting-the-selected-date) as a backing type using the correct provider and that will allow you to get the actual date instance and send the value back to the server is ISO8601 notation.

Comment: if it is not too much can I ask one more thing?  I am trying to show Australian date format in datepicker. Can you have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55633113/how-to-show-australian-date-format-in-angular and tell me what is the solution for it? Cheers.

Comment: woaww how I missed that so if I write `{provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-AU'}` it should work right?