# how to show Australian date format in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material

I am using datepicker and I have the following code:

```
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput
        [matDatepicker]="picker"
        placeholder="select a date"
        (dateChange)="setDate($event.value)">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="time" value="16:30">
  </mat-form-field>
    <input matInput value="{{ date | date: 'y-MM-dd' }}">
```

In this datepicker example there is a US date format. I would like to use Australian date format which is dd/mm/yyyy. I am able to create a hidden input and convert it to yyyy-mm-dd format for database purposes but I am unable to show dd/mm/yyyy format in the datepicker input. Could you please help me to show Australian date format instead of US date format in the datapicker field?

Also Is it a good practice the way I am sending the dateformat for DB purposes?

.TS file

```
  date: string;

  setDate(date: string) {
    this.date = date ? date : 'y-MM-dd';
```

.HTML file

```
input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="select a date"
 (dateChange)="setDate($event.value)">
```

and

```
 <input type="hidden" matInput value="{{ date | date: 'y-MM-dd' }}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to not customize your `Date` variables it in that way,

You should define your `LOCALE_ID` which means that you don't need to use custom format for your `Date` (or currency, time etc.) variables. For example,

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  providers: [{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-US' }]
});
```

Source: https://angular.io/api/core/LOCALE_ID#description

Comment: I have udated my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-date-picker-fc13tn?file=main.ts) but it's still not working. Could you please have a look where I am doing wrong?

Comment: @david83 By the way your stackblitz repo is not Angular7, I recommend you to use latest version of Angular: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3h6zsp-itogi2

Comment: thank you very much. I have updated my question. Could you please tell me if it is a  good practice the way I am sending the dateformat for DB purposes

Answer (score 0):

in your NgModule you want to assign an australian locale to LOCALE_ID....

in the providers in your NgModule add the following...

{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-au' }

(make sure you import LOCALE_ID).

Comment: thanks for the reply/ I have updated my stackblitz link but I still cannot make it work. Do you mind looking into the main.ts and tell me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Also could you please tell me if it is a good practice the way I am sending the dateformat to DB

Comment: Your stackblitz is no longer working..... but some things I did notice while checking it out.... You are using a fixed format in your date pipe.... If you want the date pipe to format according to your locale, you need "shortDate", "longDate" or some other format that changes according to your locale. Additionally, it's not good practice to put providers in your main.ts.... just put it directly in the providers of your ngModule.As for the best way to save to the server, you can either send the entire date object (JSON will parse to a UTC string, or just use .toUTCString() on the date object.